# Oracle iterate over key value pairs to generate view

Tags: sql, oracle, report

I am storing key value pairs in my database to help with normalization.  What I want to do is iterate over all of my matching key/values based on some identifier, such as 'Apple' or 'Banana' and generate a view that would be equivalent to the "full" table version of the key/value pairs.  Please see the fiddle below for more information:

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc065/1)

I presume I will have to use a cursor of sorts, but am not sure about the "best" approach for this type of problem.

Comment: In the Fiddle you grouped your objects together very nicely.  After the values inserted into the table this exact row sequence will be lost.
Without **Unique Key**, how do you know which *Apple* the values with `Apple Id` belong to?

Comment: That's not a normalized design it is [the dreaded EAV model](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html)!

Comment: @TonyAndrews while I appreciate the thought that my model is EAV as you have pointed out, it is in fact not.  The difference being in the prior schema, we had tons of null values AND the application is little more than collecting survey data.  But thank you for the insight.

Comment: @PM77-1 good question and an oversight on my part.  Let me revisit the fiddle.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: fair point - I am currently working on a generic questionnaire application myself and have a similar structure for responses: id, question_code, response_value!  If you really can't predict in advance what the "attributes" are then you are forced into a model like this!

Comment: @TonyAndrews yeah, i came into a database that was made to mirror the application.  So much rage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your IDs uniquely identified a desired row in your view (they don't in your Fiddle example) you could create a view like this:

```
create view details_view as
select id,
       max(case when key='Color' then value end) as color,
       max(case when key='Location' then value end) as location,
       max(case when key='Price' then value end) as price,
from   details
group by id;
```

I once wrote a package to help generate queries like this one - see [my blog](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/pivot).  (I also ranted against this kind of data model [here](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html)!)

Comment: I see.  So in the general solution as long as I have a unique key that I can group by a simple case statement should be sufficient?

Comment: As long as you know the maximum number of keys at design (not runtime).

Comment: This works quite nicely.  Also, I agree **completely** on the EAV model being awful.  Thankfully, I have the foresight to ensure a unique key on my tables so that I can utilize the above approach.

Comment: @PM77-1 that is a given, but I have yet to be on a project where I allow someone to dynamically add columns to my tables.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - In **your** table they **rows** (not columns). And we are talking about `view` (not table).

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle makes it evident that your data design is flawed.
In addition to using the dreaded EAV model (as pointed out by Tony Andrews), you also have a problem that there is no primary key in your table.

It is impossible to know the color, location and price of apples.
With the current setup it is impossible to know whether the apples in Texas are red or green.

The best approach for your fiddle example is to change the schema like this:

```
table fruit_details
(
    id INTEGER,  /* Generate using sequence */
    fruit_type varchar2(50),
    location   varchar2(100),
    price      number(8.2)
);
```

Comment: good insight as to what the table could potentially look like as a view.

Answer (score 0):

The id must be unique for each object. Then, the type can become another key.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebd2d/7)